# can we stop LocationListener using onPause() method in android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I am trying to stop LocationListener in GPS app when device stops moving and again i want to start it when device starts to move,

So i wanted to know, if device is not moving then does it call onPause() method dirctly from onLocationChanged()? because in my onPause() method i have written following code to stop LocationListener

```
    @Override
    public void onPause(){

     super.onPause();
     locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager = null;
       }
```

Comment: How can you tell it's moving again, if you stopped listening for position?

Comment: can we start location manager again in onResume?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do it, stop it in `onPause()`, and start it in `onResume()`. But keep in mind these callbacks correspond to your activity being in the foreground or not, and not your device moving or not.

Comment: @minipif oh thanks, it means it will not work if device stops while moving?

Comment: That's correct, when your screen turns off, `onPause()` will be called. If you want to keep on receiving location updates, you need to do it another way, but keep in mind that you will drain your user's battery really fast by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should need to define a LocationListener that is the same for the one  started and the one that is ended. and

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: does it call onPause from onLocationChanged, if device stops?

Comment: `onPause` is activity method, nothing ll be called